# Difference between running Logstash on console and service

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to index the Apache logs on my webserver, and view them on the Elasticsearch server, were also Kibana is running.
So I installed Logstash on my webserver.

If I start my Logstash conf on the console at the webserver (as root), the content is send to the ES-server, and an index is created on the ES-server.

```
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f apache2.conf
```

But if I start the Logstash service with that **same** config, the ES-server dont recieve anything.

```
systemctl start logstash
```

I checked the logs /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log and /var/log/messages , but no error entry or useful hint is included.

```
Nov 21 15:05:01 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:01,967][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
Nov 21 15:05:02 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:02,793][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://192.168.X.X:9200/]}}
Nov 21 15:05:02 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:02,809][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Running health check to see if an Elasticsearch connection is working {:healthcheck_url=>http://192.168.X.X:9200/, :path=>"/"}
Nov 21 15:05:03 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:03,230][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://192.168.X.X:9200/"}
Nov 21 15:05:03 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:03,344][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>6}
Nov 21 15:05:03 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:03,353][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>6}
Nov 21 15:05:03 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:03,398][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["http://192.168.X.X:9200"]}
Nov 21 15:05:03 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:03,441][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
Nov 21 15:05:03 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:03,507][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
Nov 21 15:05:04 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:04,367][INFO ][logstash.filters.geoip   ] Using geoip database {:path=>"/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-filter-geoip-5.0.3-java/vendor/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"}
Nov 21 15:05:05 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:05,138][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ] No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the "path" setting {:sincedb_path=>"/var/lib/logstash/plugins/inputs/file/.sincedb_d32aef0519b35231d714b89c8b4d5791", :path=>["/path/ssl_access_log", "/path/ssl_error_log"]}
Nov 21 15:05:05 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:05,193][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x634099e9 run>"}
Nov 21 15:05:05 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:05,293][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
Nov 21 15:05:05 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:05,321][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
Nov 21 15:05:05 wfe01 logstash: [2018-11-21T15:05:05,914][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

(We have another db-server with metricbeat-service installed, and this works also over the network, the content is send to the ES-server.)

ES Version 6.4 
Logstash config:

```
input {
  file {
    path => [
        "/path/ssl_access_log",
        "/path/ssl_error_log"
    ]
    start_position => "beginning"
    add_field => { "myconf" => "apache2" }
  }
}

output {
    if [myconf]=="apache2" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["http://192.168.X.X:9200"]
            index => "apache2-status-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
}
```

I tried several things: deleting the index, the since_db file, service-restarting.

What could be the problem, that the console call works, but not the service?

Thanks
Steffen

Comment: Anything in journalctl? This sounds like a permission problem to me ... or maybe it doesn't find the config file. Did you try: /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/conf.d/apache2.conf or wherever it's located for you?

Comment: Solution: the "path" (/path/ssl_access_log) had following rights:
`drwx------  2 root     root`
Changing this to
`drwxr-xr-x. 7 root     root`
solved the problem.